# Redirected, colored java console in Java Swing JTextArea. Is it possible?

Tags: java, swing, intellij-idea, console, jtextarea

I successfully redirected the `System.out` and `System.err` to the **JTextArea** followed this article: https://www.codejava.net/java-se/swing/redirect-standard-output-streams-to-jtextarea.

But the both type of messages displayed in same font color.
I want the System.err messages shows in red color, and the System.out messages shows in defined foreground color (currently white). Is it possible?

Comment: Check out the [Message Console](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/11/08/message-console/)

Comment: @camickr Thanks, this is perfect for me. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, this is not possible. A JTextArea is a simple text component that can only show one font and one font color. If you need more complexity, you need to use a more complex, powerful (and difficult to use) component, such as a JTextPane or JEditorPane.

Another option is to use a JList to display the text from the system, and give it a renderer to that it knows to display normal messages in black and err messages in red. This can be made to *look* like a JTextArea, but does have some difficulties if an individual message takes up more than one line.